# Rotating Several points inside rectangle

Tags: c, image-processing

I want to write a C program to rotate the points inside a rectangle.

In my program, the rectangle center is the pivot point and the rectangle dimensions are `320x480`. Assuming one of the vertices of the rectangle are at the origin, the pivot point is `(160,240)`.

Now to rotate the points `(px, py)` inside the rectangle with respect to the pivot `(ox, oy)`, I am using the following formulas -

```
p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox

p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

However, when I try to rotate the points by 90 degrees, all the points are mapped onto a straight line.

Can any one solve this problem?

```
theta2=90;


        theta1=abs(theta2*3.1415926)/180;

        if(theta2>0)
        {
            for(int tc=0;tc<rstruct2->nrows;tc++)
            {
                rstruct2->xcol[tc]=round((rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*cos(theta1)-sin(theta1)*(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)+160);

                rstruct2->ycol[tc]=round((rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*sin(theta1)+cos(theta1)*(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)+240);


            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int tc=0;tc<rstruct2->nrows;tc++)
            {
                rstruct2->xcol[tc]=round(160+(rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*cos(theta1)+(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)*sin(theta1));

                rstruct2->ycol[tc]=round(240+(-rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*sin(theta1)+(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)*cos(theta1));


            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. Is this c++ or c? They are different. 2. May we see your code? (This will most likely answer 1.)

Comment: Ok, I removed the `c++` tag.

Comment: ok fine how can i resolve this problem

Comment: What type are `theta1` and `theta2`?

Comment: ok i solved that problem. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your y-rotation uses modified x-value, but you need to use the base value - use a temporary variable, like this:

```
double x_tmp = round((rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*cos(theta1)-sin(theta1)*(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)+160);
double y_tmp = round((rstruct2->xcol[tc]-160)*sin(theta1)+cos(theta1)*(rstruct2->ycol[tc]-240)+240);

rstruct2->xcol[tc] = x_tmp;
rstruct2->ycol[tc] = y_tmp;
```